# How do I fix my program when it doesn't tell me any errors

Tags: python, discord.py

my program doesn't output any errors telling me what's wrong but I'm trying to assign a role to me when I type .role it just says no... go away

code:

```
async def role(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == 'ItsJustLogic#9893':
        user = ctx.message.author
        await user.add_roles('The Great Mountain Chicken')
        await ctx.send('done')
    else:
        await ctx.send('no... go away')
```

Comment: Are you sure `ctx.message.author` is `ItsJustLogic#9893`? I would add a log or breakpoint to see.

Comment: Maybe nothing is wrong if it's not telling you that anything is wrong.  It seems that "saying 'no... go away'" is a valid behavior for your code.  You should better explain what you're trying to do, what output you expect, and what you're getting.  And, as @Phix says, do whatever you need to to be sure you know what your code is really doing (via debugger, print statements or log statements).

Comment: [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) says that it should raise either [`Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Forbidden) or [`HTTPException`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.HTTPException) if something happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.message.author` returns you `discord.Member` so you cannot compare it with a string. You should use `ctx.author.name` and `ctx.author.discriminator`. `name` returns you the name, in this case it's `ItsJustLogic`, and `discriminator` returns you `9893`. So you can check your name with combining them.

Also, you can't add role with the name of the role, you have to get role with `discord.utils.get` or `guild.get_role()` then you can add the role.

```py
async def role(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    if f'{member.name}#{member.discriminator}' == 'ItsJustLogic#9893':
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='The Great Mountain Chicken')
        # or you can use role = ctx.guild.get_role(role id)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send('done')
    else:
        await ctx.send('no... go away')
```